# Laurent series $\sin(\frac{z}{1-z})$ at point $z_0 = \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I need to find the Laurent series of $$\sin\left( \frac{z}{1-z} \right)$$ at the point $z_0 = \infty$.

How I can decompose this? At point $z_0 = 1$ everything turned out well. There I tried 2 things. Firstly, I tried 
$$\frac{z}{1-z} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{z} -1} \Rightarrow \sin\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{z} - 1}\right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{z} - 1}\right)^{2n+1} (2n+1)!}
$$ 
but it looks ridiculous. Next, I tried 
$$
\sin\left(\frac{1}{z-1} -1\right) = \sin\left(\frac{1}{z}\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z}}\right)\right).$$ 
But from there on, I don't know what I should do.

Comment: What does "Laurent series at $\infty$" even mean? It's not like you can expand the function in positive and negative powers of $z-\infty$.

Comment: "Laurent series of f(z) at $z= \infty$ is well defined in Complex Analysis- it means the Laurent series of f(1/z) at z= 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laurent series you want is the same as the Laurent series of $f(1/z)$ at $z=0$.

$$f(1/z)=\sin\left(\frac1{z-1}\right)$$ which is indeed analytic at $0$.

Therefore, just proceed as you are finding its Taylor series. I do not expect that the series has a nice form.